# Importing db using spring data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

How to import Mysql db in my Java project automatically without creating manually all of db table, I have the sql script of all my db table.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used jpa tools and it work
[see picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3sF8.png)